# Transfering Text from a txt file on Assembly language

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

so I'm trying to learn assembly language using masm and doing some practice coding  and im wondering what's wrong with my code

```
.386 
.model flat,stdcall 
option casemap:none 
include \masm32\include\windows.inc 
include \masm32\include\user32.inc 
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib

.DATA
FileNameFrom db "file1.txt",0
FileNameTo db "file2.txt", 0

.DATA?
hFile HANDLE ?
hFile2 HANDLE ?
BWritten db ?
hMemory HANDLE ?
pMemory DWORD ?
SizeReadWrite DWORD ?
newfiletext dd ?

.CONST
MEMSIZE equ 65535

 .CODE
start: 

;-------;                                                       CREATE/OPEN
    push NULL
    push FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL
    push OPEN_EXISTING
    push NULL
    push 0
    push GENERIC_READ
    push offset FileNameFrom
    call CreateFile
;-------;
;or ~ invoke CreateFile,addr FileName,GENERIC_READ,0, NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL
    mov hFile, eax


    invoke GlobalAlloc, GMEM_MOVEABLE OR GMEM_ZEROINIT, MEMSIZE
    mov hMemory, eax
    invoke GlobalLock, hMemory
    mov pMemory, eax


;-------;                                                           READ
    push NULL
    push offset SizeReadWrite
    push MEMSIZE-1
    push pMemory
    push hFile
    call ReadFile
;-------;;;or ~ invoke ReadFile,hFile,pMemory, MEMSIZE-1,ADDR SizeReadWrite,NULL 



    push NULL
    push hFile
    call GetFileSize
    mov newfiletext, eax

    invoke CloseHandle, hFile
                                                                 ; WRITE


    push NULL
    push FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL
    push CREATE_ALWAYS
    push NULL
    push 0
    push GENERIC_ALL
    push offset FileNameTo
    call CreateFile
    mov hFile, eax


    push 0
    push offset BWritten
    push newfiletext     
    push offset pMemory 
    push hFile
    call WriteFile    


    invoke GlobalUnlock, pMemory
    invoke GlobalFree, hMemory
    invoke CloseHandle, hFile

end start
```

What im trying to do is open an existing file (file1) then read the contents, create another file(file2) then copy the text from file1 to file2. I'm able to create file2.txt but when i open it, it's blank.

Comment: You must be learning from a very old book. This `GlobalAlloc` and `GlobalLock` business hasn't been needed for some time. No one uses `GMEM_MOVEABLE` anymore. I also see that you do not check the return value of any of the functions you call. For example, what does `WriteFile` return? This is the part you appear to be having a problem with; does it complete successfully?

Comment: it completes successfully, no errors or anything. It also successfully creates file2.txt but its empty. I'm mostly learning online and reading functions from msdn and looking at sample codes. Sir can you suggest sites or references i can use? I'm not even aware that my reference is old. Sorry.

Comment: I don't mean assembler/compiler errors, I mean run-time errors. Windows API functions return an error code, indicating success or failure. The documentation tells you about that. For example, [WriteFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747.aspx) says that if the function succeeds, the return value is non-zero. If it fails, the return value is 0. In that case (failure; result == 0), you can call the `GetLastError` function to get an error code that describes the failure condition in detail. You have to write code to do all of this, even if only for debugging.

Comment: i get the getlasterror function, thanks for this info sir ill try to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an error in your call to `WriteFile`:

```
push offset pMemory   <-- The offset operator shouldn't be used here
push hFile
call WriteFile
```

Also, don't use `GENERIC_ALL`. Use the least amount of access rights you need, e.g. `GENERIC_WRITE` or `GENERIC_READ OR GENERIC_WRITE`. When using `GENERIC_ALL` you may be asking for access that the current user doesn't have permission for.

---

Let's add some error checking to your code:

```
include \masm32\include\msvcrt.inc
includelib  \masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib

...

szErrMsg db "GetLastError: %x",13,10,0

...
push GENERIC_ALL
push offset FileNameTo
call CreateFileA
mov hFile, eax

cmp eax,INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
jne open_ok
invoke GetLastError
invoke crt_printf,addr szErrMsg,eax
open_ok:
```

Now running the program gives us the output `GetLastError: 5` in the console. Googling for *"getlasterror codes"* yields [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx), where we find that `5` means `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

Comment: may i know what's wrong with it sir? Cause i'm successful in creating and writing a file on another program. The problem is when i integrate the 3 functions (ReadFile and CreateFile and WriteFile)

Comment: You most likely didn't use `GENERIC_ALL` in your other program. If you did, you shouldn't, as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Yep i just used GENERIC_WRITE, my bad ill try to fix it and get back to you thanks

Comment: regarding the GENERIC_ALL is it really bad? isn't it only concerned with the permissions? i mean as im just using parameters for practice (and i know its bad practice) but im just wondering does this really effect the program aside from permissions?

Comment: If you're asking for access rights that the current user doesn't have permission to, then that's not going to work.

Comment: A very common failure point is trying to open a file with write privileges that is located somewhere on the disk that the user does not have access to, such as the root directory of the disk. You'll get `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` for that, too. I can't find anywhere in the OP's code where he shows us the path that he's using.

Comment: Well, I tried the OP's code on one of my machines in a non-root directory, and it didn't work as-is. It did work after switching to `GENERIC_WRITE` and fixing the pointer issue.